# Unable to set date in lightning:input date type field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, datetime

I'm using lightning:input type="date" for a date field, but I'm not able to set today date at first. My code is this:

```
    var oggi = new Date();
    var today = oggi.getFullYear() + "/" + (oggi.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + oggi.getDate();
    component.find("mydateId").set("v.value", today);
```

and cmp code is:

```
<lightning:input aura:id="mydateId" type="date" label="Data Inizio"/>
```

Comment: shouldn't you be setting the value to v.dataInizio instead of v.value?

Comment: it doesn't work even so

Comment: do you have an attribute for it? oh nooes, you edited and removed v.dataInizio, :flip table: have you tried following the documentation, you are missing bits of code, where is your attribute?

Comment: check [Lightning Components Developer Guide for ui:inputDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputDate.htm) the examples there should help you

Comment: I've just deleted the value and the attribute because I need to access it like that for v.disabled properties of the component. Why is not working when I set the value proprerty of new Date( ) ?

Comment: did you end up adding an attributre? and check the examples from the doc i linked?

Comment: yes checked the doc you linked and just edited the post, don't know why doesn't work

Comment: You can also take a look at the aura docs in your organization that gives you information on all of the lightning components and more available to use and how to use them.  `yourdomain.com/auradocs/reference.app`  I have found this to be a valuable resource.

Answer (score 2):

A good start for learning how to lightning components work would be through Trailheads [Lightning Components Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics)

You should have (or should) declare an attribute for your date as specified in the [doc I linked](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputDate.htm) for `ui:inputDate` -> `<aura:attribute name="attrName" type="Date" default="" />`
and in your controller set the value accordingly:

```
component.set('v.attrName', yourValue)
```

you will need to reference it in your lightning:input component as you had done originaly using `v.dataInizio` however, you seem to have changed the attribute name to value for some reason.

here is a little screenshot of both components compared :
[image]

notice that the date formatting has to be formatted as YEAR-MM-DD for lightning:input to accept the value or it will default to:

[image]

and yes, if you use an aura:id, you can fetch your component and set a value to it without using attributes.

Comment: The SET is done through component.find("mydateId").set("v.value", today). The attribute is not mandatory in this case, you can easily use aura:id

Comment: overall, in your post, the code is incomplete, we don't even know how you are calling your controller function, no attributes, maybe its your date format. I copy pasted your code and followed best practices, and am able to populate a ui:inputDate as per lightning:input of type date, your date formatting seems off.

Comment: @Noomak, were you able to make it work? did you validate that your date formatting was correct for the lightning:input component?